# jenkins stuck after restarting remote service agent

Tags: bash, jenkins

This is part of bigger code that checking the OS version and choosing the correct condition by it.

( after checking OS version, it will go to this if condition: )

```
if [ "$AK" = "$OS6" ] 
    then 

    if [ "$(ls -la /etc/init.d/discagent 2>/dev/null | wc -l)" == 1 ]
        then
    
    /etc/init.d/discagent restart 2>&1 > /dev/null
    /etc/init.d/discagent status |& grep -qe 'running'
                
        if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
            echo " Done " 
        else 
            echo " Error " 

        fi
        
    fi
fi
```

If im hashing `service discagent restart` the pipeline is passing.

But if im not hashing it then it hang and not given any errors, And on the output file it is showing only the second server (out of few) that its hang on, And not moving to the next server.

what could be the issue?

p. S
while running it direct on the server it is working.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Why would you not test if the file exists w/ "[ -e ${file} ]" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this script manually on the servers, that this script will be running on.

You can use `xtrace` `-x` which would show each statement before being executed, when you use with `-v` with `-x` so this would be `-xv` and the statement would be outputted, and then the line after the output of the statement with the variables substituted before the code is substituted.

using `-u` would show you the exact error when this occurs.

Another command is the `trap` command to debug your bash script.

More information on the following webpage,
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-debug-bash-scripts